# In Unity3D (and PhysX), how do I calculate the products of inertia?

Tags: unity, physics, rigid-body-dynamics, physx

Since [unity3d](/questions/tagged/unity3d) uses [physx](/questions/tagged/physx) underneath the surface, obviously they share the same features.

One of the features is the moment of inertia tensor - [Unity3D one](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-inertiaTensor.html), [PhysX one](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/apireference/files/classPxRigidBody.html#a063cce94190de44d86a15c1b49dd7f71).

Though, they use the diagonal of the tensor, or in other words, only the moments of inertia excluding products of inertia.

Now, how would I calculate the products of inertia... I have to recalculate the whole tensor, or I can somehow extract the products?

I have checked around, but couldn't find a derivation solution (nor I know whether it is possible).

Answer (score 3):

It is a general property of rigidbodies that theier inertia tensor can be diagonalised.  This means it can be reduced to a form

```
[I1 0 0]
[0 I2 0]
[0 0 I3]
```

This is why unity and physx do not deal with the products of inertia.

It is likely that, for whatever problem you are trying to solve, it is simpler to do some rotations of your axes (in order to obtain this diagonal form) than to calculate and use all 9 elements of the tensor.  Likely, this is what unity and physx do under the hood anyway.

Source: http://www.physics.arizona.edu/~varnes/Teaching/321Fall2004/Notes/Lecture34.pdf